# how to set ng-change total with comma?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi When i use value with comma than i am not getting total value wrong how to do that?[i get total wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z30cJ.png) 
i am using ng-repeat how to set on change get total convert in with ,(comma).
i have try  with index with class but overwrite next element also.
PFA.i want if location is INDIA that time toal Like 2.5 but others than 2,5 so please guide me about my issues.

```js
// JSON Data 

$scope.data = {
   
                "fte": [
                    {
                        "year": 1996,
                        "quarters": {
                            "q3": {
                                "kk": 1.1,
                                "fl": 10.5
                            },
                            "q4": {
                                "kk": 0.1,
                                "fl": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": 1997,
                        "quarters": {
                            "q1": {
                                "kk": 0.3,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q2": {
                                "kk": 0.8,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q3": {
                                "kk": 1.1,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q4": {
                                "kk": 1.1,
                                "fl": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": 1998,
                        "quarters": {
                            "q1": {
                                "kk": 1.3,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q2": {
                                "kk": 1.4,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q3": {
                                "kk": 1.6,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q4": {
                                "kk": 1.6,
                                "fl": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": 1999,
                        "quarters": {
                            "q1": {
                                "kk": 1.4,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q2": {
                                "kk": 1.5,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q3": {
                                "kk": 1.4,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q4": {
                                "kk": 1.6,
                                "fl": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": 2000,
                        "quarters": {
                            "q1": {
                                "kk": 1.2,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q2": {
                                "kk": 1.1,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q3": {
                                "kk": 1.3,
                                "fl": 1
                            },
                            "q4": {
                                "kk": 0.8,
                                "fl": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in years.quarters"
      data-ng-init="asdasd()" class="noshadow">
      <div>
      </div>
      <span class="spanTitle">{{ key | uppercase}}</span>
      <input
         data-ng-model="(value.kk)" class="pull-left text-center noshadow valueFL"
         type="text"valid-number data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default' }"
         lang="{{gridlang}}" />
      <input
         data-ng-model="(value.fl)" class="pull-left text-center noshadow valueFL"
         type="text"valid-number data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default' }"
         lang="{{gridlang}}"  /> 
      <span class="spanInput text-center" lang="{{gridlang}}">{{ (parseFloat(value.kk) +  parseFloat(value.fl)) }}</span>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate your current output and your desired output? I think I follow, but would like clarification.

Comment: Yes sure see attachment when click here on this text i get total wrong

Comment: Write out the string that you're getting, and the string you want to get.